# java - How to split a string by character "/"?

Tags: java, split

I am attempting a programming question at hackerrank.com and is using Java language.

Part of the question required me to split a string by character `/`.

I met problems in doing this in Java.

Given input:

```
cu/a/ca ha/ri i/tu san/gat se/juk
```

My code (Java):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String source = input.next();
    String[] inputchar = source.split("/");
for (int i = 0; i < inputchar.length; i++){
    System.out.print(inputchar[i] + "\n");
}
```

Result:

```
cu
a
ca
```

But, I expected the following output:

```
cu
a
ca ha
ri i
tu san
gat se
juk
```

However, when I tried with the following C# code, it gave me the correct result.

```
    String source = Console.ReadLine();
    String[] slashchar = source.Split('/');
    for (int k = 0; k < slashchar.Length; k++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(slashchar[k]);
    }
```

I noticed the string with spaced cannot be splitted properly with my Java code.

Is there any mistakes in my Java code above?

Comment: What do you think `input.next()` does? What do you think `Console.ReadLine()` does? Why do you think so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Scanner does some **tokenizing** - on spaces. So you didn't read whole line with

```
input.next();
```

You only read until first blank.

Replace with

```
input.nextLine();
```

And try again.

Answer (score 3):

Change to  `String source = input.nextLine();` instead of `String source = input.next();` Because `input.next()` returns string till space, `input.nextLine` returns string till new line.

Answer (score 2):

With java try using `nextLine()` like this:

```
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   String source = input.nextLine();
   String[] inputchar = source.split("/");
 for (int i = 0; i < inputchar.length; i++){
  System.out.print(inputchar[i] + "\n");
}
```